# CSS3 transition on a list is ignored

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fade in a list but for some reason the transition appears to be ignored.

HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
ul {
    display:none;
    /*transition*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Is there a problem with the way I'm trying to implement this?

http://jsfiddle.net/QeG4X/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not animate the display property of css. You can do it with opacity!

Here is an updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cfknoop/QeG4X/2/

```
 ul {
    opacity:0;
    /*transition*/
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}


div:hover ul {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Another option is to animate the height i.e. of an element.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `display` is not animatable, since you want to fade in, add `opacity: 0` to `ul` and `opacity: 1` in `div:hover ul`. Note you would have to remove `display` from both rules. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QeG4X/3/